# How to set the length of arrays in a t-test function with a link to a parameter

Tags: excel

I wish to set the number of rows that are included in the arrays of a t-test function by a changeable parameter.

To be more precise, I have a slider that can be set to any number of random replicates for a t-test. But now I have to manually change the number of rows that are included in the t-test function when I include more replicates, so I would like to know how I can link the parameter from the slider to the formula of the t-test.

Comment: You will need to provide considerably more information to receive an answer. It might also help to be more specific with your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the worksheet you can use `INDEX` within `TTEST`, e.g. something like this:

`=TTEST(A1:INDEX(A1:A10,E1),B1:INDEX(B1:B10,E1),1,1)`

That assumes you start at row 1 with the number of rows determined by a number in cell E1